# Eclipse Juno: How to debug " No application id has been found"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

**The situation:**

- I build an Eclipse product with Eclipse Juno.
- Platform is Linux 32bit.
- The launcher's C-code is extended and therefore re-compiled. (I guess, that does not contribute to the problem)
- The product is not built with Eclipse's mechanism - I use a build-script that puts all components together (like Eclipse plug-ins, my own product and a lot more).

**The problem:**

The Eclipse-launcher fails as follows:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2017-09-02 19:27:12.650
!MESSAGE Product eu.esa.estec.esabase2.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 19:27:12.667
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

**The question:**
How does eclipse look for product and application ID at startup? How can I debug or solve the problem *in my Eclipse-product* which was built by my script? (Do I need to configure a certain path or put the ID or the name somewhere? I'm under Linux).

P.S. I did not invent the way the product is built and can't change this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

`EclipseAppContainer` expects the application id to be specified in the `eclipse.product` property in the `config.ini` file in the installation `configuration` directory. It will also accept a `-application` command line argument.

The product ids are found by looking at all the installed plugins and looking for products declared using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point.

Plugins which don't install properly because of some problem such as missing dependencies or requirements are not considered.

The `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` is used in a plugin.xml for one of your plugins. For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            name="product name"
            application="application id">

      ... any properties for the product

      </product>
   </extension>
```

If this is in a plugin with id 'my.plugin' then the full product id will be 'my.plugin.product'. For your product this would probably be declared in the `eu.esa.estec.esabase2` plugin.

Comment: The id is specified in the eclipse.product property in the config.ini. The first error message mentions the id ("eu.esa.estec.esabase2.product"). The question is, why is the product not found? At which places does eclipse look for the product? How is it identified?

Comment: Added details of the product id search.

Comment: So there is a folder inside the _plugins_ folder, containing the _.product_ file. This file contains the id which, Eclipse claims, can't be found.

There is no other error message. Can I therefore assume that the product-loading does not fail because of missing dependencies?

What else might be the reason that this product is not found by Eclipse?

Comment: The xxx.product file is just used during building, it is not included in the built plugins. There must be a `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point defining the product in one of your plugin's plugin.xml files and that plugin must be included in the build.

Comment: Yes, this extension point entry is present in the plugin.xml file of the relevant product. So there must be something else missing.